# IBM worklight - How to send Request Parameters to a PHP file?

Tags: php, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php

  mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysql_select_db("sowrun_mobile");

 $ad_id = $_REQUEST['ad_id'];
  $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_user_registration where reg_AD_ID='".$ad_id."'");

  $row='';
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){


    $output[]=$row;
  }

  if($row == ''){
        $out['reg_AD_ID'] = '111111';
$output[]=$out;
}



  $jsonStr = json_encode($output);
  print($jsonStr);

  mysql_close();

?>
```

I am trying to send the parameter `adid` from the Worklight adapter with the following method:

```
function getFeeds() {

    WL.Logger.debug("inside method");

    var input = {

        method : 'get',

        returnedContentType : 'json',

        path : "ios/ClientadID.php"

    };
```

`ClientadID.php` contains the code which is written in the first code sample above.

I am trying to send the request from the adapter with the following parameters while invoking
the procedure. In the parameter window I am sending `ad_id=1` but an error is throwing:

> Notice: Undefined index: ad_id in C:\wamp\www\ios\ClientadID.php
>   on line 6

Comment: Please post the code of **C:\wamp\www\ios\ClientadID.php** file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "In the parameter window". When you invoke a worklight adapter from the worklight studio, the parameter window that comes up is so that you can pass parameters to your adapter function, not REST parameters.

```
function getFeeds(myParameter) {

// myParameter is what is passed from the parameter window

WL.Logger.debug("inside method");

var input = {

    method : 'get',
    returnedContentType : 'json',
    path : "ios/ClientadID.php"

};
```

If you're trying to pass a parameter for a GET or POST request, then you need to change your adapter "input" object like this:

```
function getFeeds() {

WL.Logger.debug("inside method");

var input = {

    method : 'get',
    returnedContentType : 'json',
    path : "ios/ClientadID.php",
    parameters: {"ad_id": 1}

};
```

Comment: If you open up another question and give it the Worklight tag, either myself or one of the many other worklight users will be able to respond to you in a timely manner.